# Combine three columns in to one

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following sql statement:

```
SELECT p.id, p.first_name, p.last_name, a.admitted_at,
       a.discharged_at, c.name as client_name, p.receive_reminders,
       p.opt_in_to_receive_reminders, u.phone_number, p.status,
       c.id as client_id, p.mrn
  FROM patients p
  LEFT JOIN admissions a ON p.last_admission_id = a.id
  INNER JOIN facilities f ON f.id = p.facility_id
  INNER JOIN clients c ON c.id = f.client_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN users u ON p.user_id = u.id;
```

I have three columns:

```
p.opt_in_to_receive_reminders - boolean
u.phone_number - string
p.receive_reminders - boolean
```

I want to combine result of this 3 columns in to one virtual column - `messaging`. For example if `p.opt_in_to_receive_reminders` is true and if `u.phone_number` is not empty and `p.receive_reminders` is true then this column will have true value, in other scenario it will return false.

How can I do this in PostgreSQL?

Comment: have you see `CASE` expresion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just write this:

> p.opt_in_to_receive_reminders is true and if u.phone_number is not empty and p.receive_reminders is true

as

```
select p.opt_in_to_receive_reminders and u.phone_number is not null and p.receive_reminders
-- or
select p.opt_in_to_receive_reminders and u.phone_number <> '' and p.receive_reminders
-- or
select p.opt_in_to_receive_reminders and coalesce(u.phone_number, '') is null and p.receive_reminders
```

Comment: Neither of these expressions will work properly if phone_number is nullable. A safer expression would be SELECT p.opt_in_to_receive_reminders AND COALESCE(u.phone_number,'')<>'' AND p.receive_reminders AS messaging, ... FROM patients p ...

Comment: Thanks. The OP did not specify what it means *empty*. The first variant is for nullable values, the second for not nullable. Of course, `coalesce ()` is necessary if both cases are possible.